# Wordpress ajax and extra php scripts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a simple form I am building for my wordpress site and I cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am using ajax to call a separate php script from the generic function.php script(I called it wpplugin.php) to handle all my form data but I cant seem to figure out if my javascript file or the url for the ajax is not triggering.

So I have 3 files, I have /wpplugin.php and /upload.php with /code/upload.js.

To add the js file I use this code in wpplugin.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'all_enqueue_scripts' );
function all_enqueue_scripts()  
{
     wp_enqueue_script( 'uploadjs', plugins_url( '/code/upload.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
}
```

and my ajax from the js script is as follows:

```
$("#uploadform").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php", 
        type: "POST",       
        data: new FormData(this), 
        contentType: false,      
        cache: false,           
        processData:false,      
        success: function(data)   
        {
            arr = data;
        }
    });
}));
```

I include the js script in n html block with in wpplugin.php like so:

```
<script src="code/upload.js">
```

The feed back from wordpress is so limited I cant tell if its my ajax not triggering or js not being used. I have tested all the code in both xxamp and a generic hard coded html online site, it works.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: I was wrong, I have a few. First of all it says my ajax 3.1.0 too new.

Comment: Also says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for upload.php. Gong to find an older ajax build and see if that helps first.

Comment: Atfer fixing jquery version issue, It still cant find my upload.php  saying it fails to load after attempting post and my js scripts to failing get.

Comment: where do you add the wp_ajax function/action for your ajax ?

Comment: I dont add it, it runs from my upload.js script. Also How would I know the true link of where my files are located for my plugin?   I did change $(document).ready(function() to jQuery(document).ready( function($) { for wp in js script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script loading issue is because you're using `plugins_url()` in your `functions.php` file.

From the documentation on `plugins_url()`:

> **Retrieves the absolute URL to the plugins or mu-plugins directory** (without the trailing slash) or, when using the $path argument, to a specific file under that directory.
>
> Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

Assuming your theme directory looks like this:

```
|- style.css
|- index.php
|- functions.php
|- code
    |- upload.js
```

What you want to do is edit your `functions.php` file and replace:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'uploadjs', plugins_url( '/code/upload.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
```

with

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'uploadjs', get_template_directory() . '/code/upload.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
```

**EDIT: About upload.php**

WordPress already has a built-in system for a single ajax endpoint for every theme and plugin to use.

The endpoint address is the return value from `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`, which in practice typically works out to be `mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`.

Since every theme and plugin are using the same endpoint, how do you distinguish your calls from everyone else?

There's a special property you send across called `action`. It's what lets WordPress know who is hitting the `admin-ajax.php`.

All the info on it is here: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

A quick sample of what it will look like is this:

**JS**

```
$("#uploadform").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=akamaozu_do_frontend_upload", 
        type: "POST",       
        data: new FormData(this)
    });
}));
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_akamaozu_do_frontend_upload', 'handle_signed_in_uploads' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_akamaozu_do_frontend_upload', 'handle_signed_out_uploads' );
```

Comment: What about the 'upload.php' in my ajax function? Or will this now correctly pull the javascript aligning the original directory call to be the same for my ajax call anyways?

Comment: Thanks you helped a bunch. Much appreciated .

Comment: Hi I get this now /wp-content/themes/dance/code/upload.js?ver=1.0 404 (Not Found) It seems to be pulling the link from the theme not plugins. which makes sense as that is the template. Also <script src="code/upload.js"> is still pulling from the wrong place can that function be used here as well or limited to pure php?

Comment: @Kbcoder I mentioned that if your directory structure looked a certain way, that's what your code will look like. You need to figure out where `code/upload.js` is in relation to your theme's `function.php` and update `wp_enqueue_script` to match it.